# отправка письма с помощью sendmail

Tags: php, sendmail

2 день пытаюсь найти решение в интернете не получается, многое что перепробовал
надеюсь вы мне помочь сможете использую Xampp)

## код

```
<?php
$to = 'we1we1z98@yandex.com';
$subject = 'Test email'; 
$message = "Hello World!\n\nThis is my first mail."; 
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message );
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
?>
```

## php.ini

```
SMTP=smtp.yandex.com

smtp_port=25

sendmail_from =we1we1z98@yandex.com
```

## sendmail.ini

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.yandex.ru;

smtp_port=25;

; SMTPS (SSL) support

;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS

;   ssl  = alway use SSL

;   tls  = always use TLS

;   none = never try to use SSL

smtp_ssl=auto

default_domain=yandex.com

error_logfile=error.log

debug_logfile=debug.log

auth_username=we1we1z98@yandex.com

auth_password=****

pop3_server=pop.yandex.com

pop3_username=we1we1z98@yandex.com

pop3_password=****

force_sender=we1we1z98@yandex.com

;force_recipient=

hostname=yandex.com
```

В чем проблема??? почему не отправляется письмо??

Comment: Что говорят логи? - как минимум можно посмотреть процесс коннекта, EHLO и т.д. и где этот процесс обрывается.

Comment: sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing.              Sendmail_form так же установлен sendmail_from =we1we1z98@yandex.com

Comment: по какой-то причине не подхватывается sendmail_from. Вы уверены, что редактировали верный php.ini? Сервер перезапускали? Что вернет ini_get('sendmail_from')? Что будет, если установить переменную через ini_set()? Что будет, если в скрипт скормить [заголовки](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631726/trying-to-send-an-email-using-php-scripting)?

Comment: сервер забыл перезапустить, спасибо ))